# FieldsGrouping from multiple Streams in a Bolt in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I have 2 named streams in my code and want to send the tuples from both the streams to a bolt using fieldsGrouping. The source of both the streams is same bolt.
So, if my source bolt is `previousBolt` and the target bolt is `nextBolt` and streams are named `stream1` and `stream2`, this is what I want to achieve -

```
topologybuilder.setbolt(nextBolt, IRichBolt, parallelism_hint)
.fieldsGrouping(previousBolt,"stream1",new Fields(somefield))
.fieldsGrouping(previousBolt,"stream2",new Fields(somefield))
```

I thought this should have worked, but I am getting a NullPointerException at the point of second fieldsGrouping `.fieldsGrouping(previousBolt,"stream2",new Fields(somefield))` when the topology is being built. 
Kindly help me in identifying what I am missing here. Thanks!

Comment: If you post the stack trace it will be easier to tell what's happening

Comment: Sorry, my bad, actually there wasn't any issue. My code was actually failing in the Unit Test as I forgot to add the Mockito stubs when fieldsgrouping is requested.